# Android query where clause on ListView

Tags: android, cursor, android-listview, contextmenu

I created a `ListView` with a `CursorAdapter`, populated by a table of my db. After I added a `ContextMenu` that with a long click on the desired line of `ListView` pick info from my table.

The problem is that: I can not collect the information of that single line of `ListView`, each line gives me the same result. I think I do something wrong in query.

`onCreate`:

```
private void createTabRegistry(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE {0} ({1} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, {2} TEXT,{3} INTEGER,{4} TEXT,{5} TEXT,{6} TEXT, {7} TEXT);";
            db.execSQL(MessageFormat.format(sql, TabRegistry.TABLE_NAME, TabRegistry._ID,TabRegistry.TYPE, TabRegistry.DATE, TabRegistry.STATUS, TabRegistry.NUMBER, TabRegistry.MESSAGE, TabRegistry.OTHER));
    }
```

My query in db class:

```
public Cursor getRegistry2(long id) {
        return (getReadableDatabase().query(
            TabRegistry.TABLE_NAME, 
            TabRegistry.COLUMNS,
            TabRegistry._ID + " = " + id,
            null,
            null,
            null, 
            null, 
            null));
    }
```

id of `ContextMenu` in my activity:

```
 AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info= (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
 id = getListAdapter().getItemId(info.position);
```

My cursor in the activity class:

```
Cursor c3 = databaseHelper.getRegistry2(id);
if (c3 != null) {
        c3.moveToFirst();
    }                     

dbnumber = (c3.getString(c3.getColumnIndex(TabRegistry.NUMBER)));
```

How do I assign to `dbnumber` string the value of the line of `ListView` that wonder?

EDIT code that works, but reset the view of listview....

```
Cursor c3 = (Cursor) getListAdapter().getItem(info.position);
                        startManagingCursor(c3);
                          aaaaa = c3.getString(c3.getColumnIndex(TabRegistry.NUMBER));
                         c3.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo` has a field called `id` that represents the row id from the database of that selected row. You'll want to query for that id and not the `position` field that represents the position in the list:

```
rowId = info.id;
```

and then query your database for the `rowId` to get that item's data.

**Edit:**

You'll probably don't want to use the solution you added. You close the cursor so no more data(that is why you have to restart the activity, as you probably query the database only in the `onCreate` method).

I told you the check if `info.id` returns different values when you use long press(to show the `ContextMenu`) different rows in the list, that means that the `ContextMenu`(probably) selects different row ids for different rows).

I don't know what causes your issue(if the delete works I would say there is something in the activity), so I made a small example of what you are trying to do so you can see this type of code:

http://pastebin.com/Yri03S0T

Comment: thanks for the answer.... but I have not solved .... I have always the same value for all rows in the listview, what should I change more?

Comment: @Tony Do you use a custom `CursorAdapter` or the standard one from the android `SDK`? And which value do you always get from the list(0,1, 2..etc?), which position?

Comment: I use a custom `CursorAdapter` ... and I have always the same result as the first line of my listview ... I think it's because of `c3.moveToFirst();`

Comment: @Tony By any chance do you override the method `getItemId` in that custom `CursorAdapter`? That method is responsible for getting the row id when an item is clicked in the list or in the `ContextMenu`(your case). If you do implement that method is important to implement it correctly.

Comment: No I do not have, However, the `db.delete` works perfectly,this found the true line in the `listview`..

Comment: @toney Maybe you should add all the code regarding your database operations.

Comment: @Tony I've seen your edit but I don't see anything wrong. Try to debug your app and see if `info.id` returns the exact long value no matter what row you click. If it does then you're doing something wrong in the activity. If not there is something else when you query the database that goes wrong.

Comment: I did not understand very well ..What value should I expect?. However, doing some tests I found that: the value of info.id increases by 1 every time insert a new row in my listview, for exemple for 3 row, info.id = 3, for 4... info.id = 4 etc..

Comment: edit: I added in my first post, a way that works, this takes the true value, but once taken clearing the view of listview and i need to reopen the activity to take another value... I added the code in the first post, at the last position...how to improve this code? thanks for your help.

Comment: thanks for your example, I have been very useful..But I have not yet fully solve the problem .... I always need to reopen the activity for the true values.. ​​at the moment I used a command for reopen the activity and work around the problem.